# Have org-mode's exported HTML use CUSTOM_ID when linking to sub-sections in TOC

Tags: org-mode

If I have an org-mode buffer like that looks like:

```
* My headline
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: id1
:END:
* My second headline
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: id2
:END:
```

And I export this to HTML with a table-of-contents, the table of contents uses `#sec-1` and `#sec-2` as the anchor links for each headline.

I would like it to automatically use `#ID-id1` and `#ID-id2` so that I can change the order of the headlines without changing where the links point to. Is there a way to tell org-mode to export the table of contents using these anchors instead?

**EDIT** As Jonathan suggested below, I have created a custom function to use `:CUSTOM_ID:` instead, here is my setup in case others find it useful:

```
(defun my/org-custom-id-get (&optional pom create prefix)
  "Get the CUSTOM_ID property of the entry at point-or-marker POM.
If POM is nil, refer to the entry at point. If the entry does not
have an CUSTOM_ID, the function returns nil. However, when CREATE
is non nil, create a CUSTOM_ID if none is present already. PREFIX
will be passed through to `org-id-new'. In any case, the
CUSTOM_ID of the entry is returned."
  (interactive)
  (org-with-point-at pom
    (let ((id (org-entry-get nil "CUSTOM_ID")))
      (cond
       ((and id (stringp id) (string-match "\\S-" id))
        id)
       (create
        (setq id (org-id-new prefix))
        (org-entry-put pom "CUSTOM_ID" id)
        (org-id-add-location id (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer)))
        id)))))

(defun my/org-add-ids-to-headlines-in-file ()
  "Add CUSTOM_ID properties to all headlines in the
current file which do not already have one."
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries (lambda () (my/org-custom-id-get (point) 'create))))

;; automatically add ids to captured headlines
(add-hook 'org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook
          (lambda () (my/org-custom-id-get (point) 'create)))))
```

Which I can then use the `my/org-add-ids-to-headlines-in-file` function to add `:CUSTOM_ID:` properties to each headline in a file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest solution to get this to work would be to substitute your cases of `:ID:` with `:CUSTOM_ID:`, those will be used without any further work required.

Both `:ID:` and `:CUSTOM_ID:` have targets created at the headline to allow for linking using them (in addition to the `sec-#` targets).

#### Source

In `ox-html.el` there is `org-html--format-toc-headline` which is used to create the TOC contents for the headline.  Relevant portion of the function:

```
(format "<a href=\"#%s\">%s</a>"
        ;; Label.
        (org-export-solidify-link-text
         (or (org-element-property :CUSTOM_ID headline)
             (concat "sec-"
                 (mapconcat #'number-to-string headline-number "-"))))
        ;; Body.
        (concat
         (and (not (org-export-low-level-p headline info))
              (org-export-numbered-headline-p headline info)
              (concat (mapconcat #'number-to-string headline-number ".")
                  ". "))
         (apply (plist-get info :html-format-headline-function)
                todo todo-type priority text tags :section-number nil)))
```

Using `:ID:` by changing ox-html

If you change the link portion above from:

```
(org-export-solidify-link-text
         (or (org-element-property :CUSTOM_ID headline)
             (concat "sec-"
                 (mapconcat #'number-to-string headline-number "-"))))
```

To

```
(org-export-solidify-link-text
         (or (org-element-property :CUSTOM_ID headline)
             (org-element-property :ID headline)
             (concat "sec-"
                 (mapconcat #'number-to-string headline-number "-"))))
```

It will use the generated/set IDs.

#### `:ID:` vs `:CUSTOM_ID:`

If a property `:CUSTOM_ID:` is set, it will be used for the link ID, however an `:ID:` property will not.  Looking elsewhere through org code, `:ID:` is meant for use by org-internals while `:CUSTOM_ID:` is meant for the user.

`:ID:` is used for determining the folder to store attachments in, with `org-id` it is used to allow crosslinking between multiple org-files with guaranteed unique IDs.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'd like, the reason I am using `:ID:` is because I am using `org-id-get-create` to create the ID, is there a way to have `org-id-get-create` generate `:CUSTOM_ID:` instead of `:ID:`?

Comment: Looks like `org-id-get` hardcodes the `ID` property when creating a new ID.  You would have to create a new function (even if just by duplicating `org-id-get` and change `ID` to `CUSTOM_ID`.